# Splitting a large views.py into smaller pieces

Tags: python, django, import, circular-dependency

I have a huge `views.py` file and so I split it up into `views.py` and `admin_views.py`. Since the functions tend to depend on functions in the other file, I did the following:

```
# views.py
from admin_views.py import a,b,c

# admin_views.py
from views.py import d,e,f
```

I found out this results in a circular dependency, and the imports don't work. 
What is the best approach to solve this problem? I know I could put import statements at the bottom of the file, but that doesn't seem too elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make a view package.

```
--view
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ main.py # previewsly view.py
  |_ admin.py # previewsly view_admin.py
```

Then, add a new file that will include the part you need to import in `main` or `admin`:

```
--view
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ main.py 
  |_ admin.py 
  |_ base.py
```

Then move the imports so they import both from `base`.

Eventually, in `__init__`, import stuff you need from main et admin. Every thing you import in `__init__` will be available to import using from views import stuff.

Comment: Cool! So `base.py` is importing stuff from both `main.py` and `admin.py`? When I import `base.py` from `main.py` doesn't that create a circular dependency as well? How can I get around that? Sorry, maybe I didn't understand your explanation well

Comment: "Then move the imports so they import both FROM base." The common code should be in base.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have core logic in views.py files.  You should put this core logic into other python files (some logic is appropriate for the models.py or forms.py) and import it into the views.py.  Basically the only place you should be importing a views.py file in most cases is into the urls.py file. The urls.py file also can be in a format such as:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('management.views',
    #url(r'^index/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'stats/index.html'},
    #    name="index"),          
    url(r'^pay_invoices/$', 'pay_invoices', name='pay_invoices'), 
)
```

This makes it so that a views.py function basically never need be imported anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Is the circular import to do with a foreign key relationship?

If so you can define the class as a string.

```
item = models.ForeignKey("SomeOtherClass")
```

Failing that I normally extract out the logic to a third file like e-satis suggested.